# Getting error at line 39 saying Incompatible value type String for Map<Id,User>

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex, singleemailmessage

I have written one batch class and i am taking a count of No_of_active_CP_on_Account__c and No_of_active_CP_on_Contact__c .I need to send mail to Account owner once batch apex runs.

So for retrieving email id of account owner first i am getting owner id and then i am checking into User table for the same id so that i can get email of that account owner.

But i am getting error at line 39

```
emailMap.put(u.Id, u.Email);
```

Batch Apex class :

```
public class BatchApexUpdateNoOfActiveAccountContact implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([select Id from Account order by Name]);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Account> scope) {
        Account[] updates = new Account[] {};
        //Map<Id, Account> mapacc = new Map<Id, Account>();
        List<Id> idofacc = new List<Id>();
        for (AggregateResult ar : [
                select  Account__c a, count(Id) c
                from Contact_Point__c
                where Status__c=true and Account__c in :scope
                group by Account__c
                ]) {
           set<id> ids=new set<id>();
           for(contact com:[SELECT id,firstname,AccountId FROM Contact where accountid =:(Id)ar.get('a')])
           {
            ids.add(com.id);
            }
        Decimal dec=[Select count() from Contact_Point__c
                        where Status__c=true and Contact__c in :ids];
        updates.add(new Account(id=(Id)ar.get('a'),No_of_active_CP_on_Account__c =(decimal)ar.get('c'),No_of_active_CP_on_Contact__c =dec));
          idofacc.add((Id)ar.get('a'));          
                }
        update updates;
        System.debug('value of updates :::: '+updates);
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        EmailTemplate et = [Select id from EmailTemplate where name=:'Contact Point'];
        Map<Id, User> emailMap = new Map<Id, User>();
        List<Account> ls = [select Id,ownerid FROM Account where Id=:idofacc];
        List<Id> ownid = new List<Id>();
        for(Account acc: ls){
         ownid.add(acc.ownerid);
        }
        List<User> mailid = [Select Id,Email FROM User WHERE Id =:ownid];
            for(User u :mailid){
                emailMap.put(u.Id, u.Email);
            }
        mail.setToAddresses(emailMap);
        mail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
        Messaging.sendEmail(New Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{mail});
        }



    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {



    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared your emailMap as a map if **Id-User** key-value pair.

but when populating the map you are adding **Id-User.Email** into it which is why you are getting this error.

to fix this, change your map value type to string

```
Map<Id, String> emailMap = new Map<Id, String>();
```

also i noticed couple of other things..

your SOQL query should use IN instead of =

```
List<User> mailid = [Select Id,Email FROM User WHERE Id in :ownid];
```

and you are passing the entire map to the `setToAddresses` method which might not work. just pass the values from the map

```
mail.setToAddresses(emailMap.values());
```

Comment: Thanks Krishna,
I have following things in updates array.I need to access No_of_active_CP_on_Account__c & No_of_active_CP_on_Contact__c fields from updates how can i do that as it is throwing me variable not found error.
value of updates :::: (Account:{Id=00128000006bm2hAAA, No_of_active_CP_on_Account__c=2, No_of_active_CP_on_Contact__c=0}, Account:{Id=00128000006bm2dAAA, No_of_active_CP_on_Account__c=2, No_of_active_CP_on_Contact__c=1})

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
emailMap.put(u.Id, u);
```

Comment: This one line of code could be part of an answer, but just changing this one line would create other problems that you should address in your post.

Comment: That issue got resolved but i need values of No_of_active_CP_on_Contact__c &
No_of_active_CP_on_Account__c as i need to include these values in mail.So how to access these values from updates array.